# Geometric interpretation of Gaussian curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

We have the following result from Do Carmo book of differential Geometry:
"Let $p$ be a point of a surface $\Sigma$ such that the Gaussian curvature $K(p) \neq 0$, and let $V$ be a connected neighborhood of $p$ where $K$ doesn't change sign. Then
$$ K(p)= \lim_{A \rightarrow 0} \frac{A'}{A} ,$$
where $A$ is the area of a region $B \subset V$ containing $p$, $A'$ is the area on the image of $B$ by the Gauss map $N: \Sigma \rightarrow S^2$, and the limit is taken through a sequence of region $B_n$ that converges to $p$, in the sense that any sphere around $p$ contains all $B_n$, for $n$ large enought". How can I prove, using this result, that is $\Sigma$ is a compact surface
$$ \int_{\Sigma}|K| \ge 4 \pi \,\,\,? $$

Comment: A couple of hints (whose usefulness may depend on how much "you know (at this stage of the book)" about closed surfaces in space: The $4\pi$ comes from the area of the unit sphere. Show $N$ is surjective (this may require a geometric argument relying on the fact that $\Sigma$ is the boundary of a compact region), then use the change of variables theorem to express the integral of $|K| = |\det DN|$ over $\Sigma$ in terms of the area of $S^{2}$.

Comment: @user86418 I can prove that the Gauss map is surjective, but I don't know how to continue....

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198377/proof-that-the-gaussian-curvature-is-a-ratio-of-areas), particularly the comment involving the change of variables theorem, should help finish the proof. :)

Comment: $\int_{\Sigma} |K| \ge \int_{\Sigma}K = \int_{\Sigma} dN_p dA_{\Sigma} = \int_{S^2} dA_{S^2} = 4 \pi  $. Is it correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?": That's the general idea, but it's not quite OK as stated. It turns out that the total curvature of a closed surface is $2\pi$ times its Euler characteristic, which can be non-positive. Rather than dropping the absolute value, use the fact that integrating $|\det DN|$ gives the _unsigned_ area of the image of $N$ (i.e., area not counting orientation; if $N$ "folds back on itself", the multiply-covered area gets counted multiple times with a positive sign).

Comment: $ 4 \pi = \mathcal{A}(S^2) = \int_{S^2} 1 \, d\mathcal{A}_{S^2} = \int_{\Sigma}|Jac(N)(p)| .$
We have by definition
$ |Jac(N)(p)|= |(dN)_p(e_1) \wedge (dN)_p(e_2)| ,$
where $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is an o.n. basis of $T_p\Sigma$. We choose $e_1$ and $e_2$ as the principal direction $\Sigma$ in $p$. We obtain
$$ |Jac(N)(p)|=|k_1(p)k_2(p)||e_1 \wedge e_2|= K(p) .$$
So to finish:
$$ 4 \pi = \int_{\Sigma} K \le \int_{\Sigma} |K| .$$ I have a problem with the module also in this case...

Comment: You're basically there. :) Two small things: In your first displayed equation, the right-hand side is $|K(p)|$. Second, $\int_{S^{2}} dA \leq \int_{\Sigma} |\operatorname{Jac}(N)|\, dA_{\Sigma}$; generally the image may be multiply-covered. In other words, if $\Sigma' \subset \Sigma$ is mapped _bijectively_ (except possibly for boundary points) to $S^{2}$ by $N$, then $4\pi = \int_{\Sigma'} |K|\, dA_{\Sigma'}$. (When you get things worked out, it's a good idea to post your solution as an answer.:)

Comment: Ok, thank you! The last thing: can I argue something about the elliptic or hyperbolic nature of the points of $\Sigma$? Is it possible to say that $\Sigma$ has an elliptic point? Moreover, is it possible to say that if $\int_{\Sigma}|K|=4 \pi$ than $\Sigma$ has not hyperbolic points?

Comment: Every closed surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ has an elliptic point: find a point $p$ at maximum distance from the origin, look at the sphere centered at the origin and through $p$.... Your second claim looks correct.